# PHP Mysql increment a column during insert

Tags: php, mysql, increment

Sorry, let me try to explain  ....   recordID auto increments and is my primary key ..... LISTINGID refers to the ID in a different table. In this table 1 need to increment recordListingID for each record that has the same LISTINGID. My insert statement inserts upto 10 records that have the same LISTINGID I need the the recordListingID to start at 1 and so on.

Hi guys

I am inserting records into mysql from php it can be 1 or more records I need one of the cols to increment with the first entry being 1 here is my insert code

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO car_listing_images (recordID, recordText, recordListingID,   LISTINGID) VALUES ('', '$fileName', '??', '$listingid')");
```

where I have put ?? is the col that needs to increment. How can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use Auto-increment for that field.....

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built in Auto_Increment function of MySql

```
  AUTO_INCREMENT
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

MySql would increment the specified field by 1 (Or what ever interval you set)

Comment: this is NOT the answer, he wants a non-primary key to increment

Comment: Thats no good for me because the col that I want to increment does not hold unique data. I already do that for recordID

Comment: If you dont want a primary key remove the Primary key Referance then - That was my mistake.

Comment: Any reason this got a downvote? Please share, If I'm incorrect then let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [user-defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)

Answer (score 1):

A preface: If you need to have 2 fields that increment, but are not tied to each other, you are probably doing it wrong. It might be better to not have `recordListingID` and instead just use the `recordID` as they will probably be the same number.

If your tables are running `InnoDB` you can create transactions. Then you can try something like this:

```
<?php

mysql_query('START TRANSACTION');

$recordListingId = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT count(*)+1 as num FROM car_listing_images WHERE LISTINGID=$listingid"), 'num', 0);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO car_listing_images (recordID, recordText, recordListingID,   LISTINGID) VALUES ('', '$fileName', '$recordListingId', '$listingid')");

mysql_query('COMMIT');
?>
```

If you don't have innodb, try using a [stored procedure](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,358569,358569).

Comment: OK  recordID already auto increments,   for each recordID recordListingID can have a value of 1 up to 10. Many recordIDs can have these values in recordListingID

Comment: Okay, I added a `"WHERE LISTINGID=$listingid"` to the first sql query. This should go in your loop of adding 10 items. Each time you add an item with the same `LISTINGID` it will increment `$recordListingId`. This will also allow you to come back later and add records with the same `LISTINGID` without having to keep track of the values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I really understand your question.

If you're wanting to increment a column with every record, it should be defined as an [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html) column. This way, in your `INSERT` statement if you insert `NULL` into that column, it will go up every time.

Alternatively you could do `fieldname+1`, but `AUTO_INCREMENT` is always preferred.

---

As per my comment, you could do something like this:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT MAX(recordListingID) AS `max` FROM car_listing_images"));
$next_id = $row['max'] + 1;
mysql_query("INSERT INTO car_listing_images (recordID, recordText, recordListingID,   LISTINGID) VALUES ('', '$fileName', '$next_id', '$listingid')");
```

I would still seriously recommend against this, it's a much **much** better implementation to use an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field.

---

After your last comment I would suggest the following. You will not be able to do this in MySQL directly (unless you use a variable, but this may go wrong if you're inserting multiple RecordIDs too).

```
$next_id = 0;
foreach ($insert as $insert_stmt) {
    $next_id++;
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO car_listing_images (recordID, recordText, recordListingID,   LISTINGID) VALUES ('', '$fileName', '$next_id', '$listingid')");
}
```

Comment: $mylid = 0;
mysql_query("INSERT INTO car_listing_images (recordID, recordText, recordListingID, LISTINGID) VALUES ('', '$fileName', '$mylid+1', '$listingid')");

Comment: No, sorry, you'd need to do this in the query and I'm not sure it's really possible in a simple insert statement. You could have an internal counter when doing the inserts, or select MAX, see my updated answer (give me a minute).

Comment: Sorry, let me try to explain .... recordID auto increments and is my primary key ..... LISTINGID refers to the ID in a different table. In this table 1 need to increment recordListingID for each record that has the same LISTINGID. My insert statement inserts upto 10 records that have the same LISTINGID I need the the recordListingID to start at 1 and so on.

Comment: $next_id = 0;
foreach ($insert as $insert_stmt) {
    $next_id++;
    $insert_stmt = "INSERT INTO car_listing_images (recordID, recordText, recordListingID,   LISTINGID) VALUES ('', '$fileName', '$next_id', '$listingid')";
 $insert = mysql_query($insert_stmt) or die(mysql_error());
}

Comment: That should work fine, do you get an error? Although you should note that if `$insert` is empty it's not going to work. You should instead use a `for` loop with a specific count, or loop over a data array (ie. whenever the query needs to get ran).

Comment: $next_id = 0;
$next_id++;
    $insert_stmt = "INSERT INTO car_listing_images (recordID, recordText, recordListingID,   LISTINGID) VALUES ('', '$fileName', '$next_id', '$listingid')";
 $insert = mysql_query($insert_stmt) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: The problem with that is that the ID would always be one. The `++` operation needs to be within a loop at the same time that your query is called. But if that's not your *exact* code and it's working for you - You're very much welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

Alter your table structure to include the [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) attribute for your recordListingID column, then omit the column from your insert to have it auto-populate with an incremental number.

I.e: mysql_query("INSERT INTO car_listing_images (recordID, recordText, LISTINGID) VALUES ('', '$fileName', '$listingid')");

Answer (score 0):

You can initialise the variable as 1 and use the [post-increment operator](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php):

```
$value = 1;
for(...){
    $sql = 'INSERT ...';
    $value++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think i know what you were/are trying to accomplish. there may be a better way to it, but what i did was to "select max(id)+1 as nextId from table" and store that in a variable that i used in the secondary id field that you called "recordListingID."

that way the first row you insert will have the same id and recordListingID, but each other row will auto_inc the id, but the recordListingID will be the same as the first.

in my situation, there is only one user doing this at a time, so there is no chance of errors, but in a multi-user situation, you may want to modify this to watch out for people doing inserts at the same time. like maybe marking the last row so your query knows it's finished so you could so something like "select max(id)+1 as nextId from table where lastRow =1" or something like that.